# how often Jenkins should be upgraded

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Currently we have the version 2.200 installed and we want to upgrade it. I want to know what is the best way to do it.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the LTS [(point - ie; 2.204.6)](https://www.jenkins.io/download/) - for Production. Read the [upgrade guides](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/).

Read [my prior advice](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9749/13379).

In upgrading, I'd suggest take the latest release of each LTS in sequence (2.204.6 / 2.222.4 / 2.235.5, etc). You could chance skipping one if no significant changes.

Best to not fall more than 2 LTS behind. use a backup instance  to upgrade and validate every bump.